# Wordpress plugin to create virtual page using rewrite rules

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm creating a plugin that will need virtual pages to output content on the front end.

Here is my code:

```
add_filter( 'generate_rewrite_rules', function ( $wp_rewrite ) {
$wp_rewrite->rules = array_merge(
    ['my-custom-url/?$' => 'index.php?custom=1'],
    $wp_rewrite->rules
);
} );

add_filter( 'query_vars', function( $query_vars ) {
$query_vars[] = 'custom';
return $query_vars;
} );

add_action( 'template_redirect', function() {
$custom = intval( get_query_var( 'custom' ) );
if ( $custom ) {
    include plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . 'templates/states.php';
    exit();
 }
} );
```

In the plugin I have templates/states.php and in that file I have:

```
<?php
$state = get_query_var( 'custom' );

echo $state;
?>
```

When I visit localhost/my-custom-url/somevariable I get a page not found from Wordpress. I've tried flushing my permalinks.

Comment: I have never used `generate_rewrite_rules` but if this `'my-custom-url/?$` is a Regex, you need to at least remove the `$` as that means the end of string for the match, so this only matches if the URL ends in `my-custom-url` with an optional slash.  `When I visit localhost/my-custom-url/somevariable I get a page not found` - not surprising.given what I said ...

Comment: I had the same problem. It was browser cache. I tried in different browser and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

As I said in the comments

> I have never used generate_rewrite_rule

The documentation on it is pretty weak too.  But this key looks just like I would expect a Regular expresion to be. And, that makes sense as that is how real Mod Rewrite and Htaccess work.

```
add_filter( 'generate_rewrite_rules', function ( $wp_rewrite ) {
  $wp_rewrite->rules = array_merge(
    ['my-custom-url/?$' => 'index.php?custom=1'],
    $wp_rewrite->rules
  );
} );
```

So this `$` here matches the end of the string, this means your URL must end with `my-custom-url` with an optional `/` because of the `?`.

> When I visit localhost/my-custom-url/somevariable I get a page not found

That's **not** surprising as your URL does not end in a way that will match that pattern.

[Test it yourself!](https://regex101.com/r/ZbcOMx/1)

So you can just remove the `$` you may or may not want to keep the `/` optional.

```
add_filter( 'generate_rewrite_rules', function ( $wp_rewrite ) {
  $wp_rewrite->rules = array_merge(
    ['my-custom-url/?' => 'index.php?custom=1'],
    $wp_rewrite->rules
  );
} );
```

One note is this will make that match anywhere in the URL

[Test this one](https://regex101.com/r/ZbcOMx/2)

Hope it works.